# Distribution of random variable on disk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is a random variable uniformly distributed over the unit disk:

$D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$

Define $Z = X/||X||_2$

- What is the distribution of Z?
- Are X and Z independent?

I initially guessed they wouldn’t be independent and that Z is uniformly distributed on the boundary of $D$. Is this correct?

Comment: But $\|X\|_2$ and $Z$ *are* independent. 

**Hint:** Polar coordinates.

Comment: Indeed. Good observation.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is yes : $Z$ is uniformly distributed on the unit circle.

The second answer is yes, they are dependent.

Indeed, calling (I) and (II) the two first open quadrants :

$$\underbrace{P(X \in (I) \ \ \text{and} \ \ Z \in (II))}_{=0} \ne \underbrace{P(X \in (I))}_{=1/4} \times  \underbrace{P(Z \in (II))}_{=1/4}$$

Therefore, random variables $X$ and $Z$ are not independent.

Comment: Oh, I said that they are not independent. So I guess we agree :)